# Remove "duplicate" formulas

Tags: perl, duplicates

I made a program that will take in 5 numbers and will use the first four to acquire the fifth number as a solution. Solutions can only contain positive integers, and the only operators acceptable are "+ - * /". There are 11 different way that the numbers and operators can be arranged with parentheses.  Ex "(n @ n) @ n @ n" where n represents numbers and @ represents operators.

I have no problem finding all the solutions, my problem is removing "duplicates". I have been able to remove most duplicates using

```
%Seen = ();
@solutions = grep { ! $Seen{ $_ }++ } @solutions;
```

However I am unable to figure out a way to remove "duplicate" formulas.

Using 21 14 2 7 to acquire 34 gives us 4 solutions after the first duplicates have been removed. Here they are

```
21/7=3; 14+3=17; 2*17=34
21/7=3; 3+14=17; 2*17=34
21/7=3; 3+14=17; 17*2=34
21/7=3; 14+3=17; 17*2=34
```

My teacher considers these mathematically the same and as such all four of them are just 1 solution. What I can't figure out how to do is find these "duplicates" and remove them. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more generic form of the dedupping code you used is

```
grep !$seen{key($_)}++, ...
```

In this case, `key` would be

```
sub key {
   ( my $key = $_[0] ) =~ s/(\d+)([*+])(\d+)/ $1 < $3 ? "$1$2$3" : "$3$2$1" /eg;
   return $key;
}
```

In your case, you might want to simply normalise your inputs first

```
sub normalise(_) {
   ( my $s = $_[0] ) =~ s/(\d+)([*+])(\d+)/ $1 < $3 ? "$1$2$3" : "$3$2$1" /eg;
   return $s;
}

@solutions = grep !$seen{$_}++, map normalise, @solutions;
```

Comment: I believe you want the comparisons to be `$1 < $3`, not `$1 < $2`.

Comment: I really like this solution, but I can't seem to edit its format. Right now it would return something like "3+10=13 1+4=5; 13-5=8" however I would prefer it to return "10+3=13; 4+1=5; 1-5=8"
I tried editing it myself by changing the ternary check and the values but I can't seem to figure out a solution (I feel pretty stupid...)

Comment: If you want the larger first, use the second solution and simply change `<` to `>`.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I wasn't using map right.
`@solutions = grep !$seen{$_}++, map normalise($_), @solutions;` works but
`@solutions = grep !$seen{$_}++, map normalise, @solutions;` doesn't.

Comment: Did you omit the `(_)`? That tells Perl to use `$_` if no arg is specified.

Comment: No it's there, which is why I was unsure at first why it wasn't working, but as soon as I changed the above line it worked no problems.

Answer (score 3):

For example, for commutative operations, only consider `x @ y` where `x <= y`. This way, `2 * 17` is possible, but `17 * 2` is not.